# javascript - access iframe's elements

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the style of my frame element, however the iframe has no id or class or name

```
<div id="A">
        <iframe src="iframe-left.html">
            <div class="login" style="display : none;"> </div>
        </iframe>
</div>
<div id="B">
    <iframe src="iframe-right.html">
       <button onclick = "execute()">Submit</button>
    </iframe>
</div>

function execute()
{
    parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector(".login").style.display = 'block';
}
```

What's the mistake in the javascript function?

Comment: You do know that with your makup as it is, the elements inside the iframe tags only render if the browser of the user cannot render the iframes (which is never).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you have to get the first element of the node list, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

In other words you have to do:

```
parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.querySelector(".login").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much :D

Comment: How does `parent.document` supposed to work? The function is being called from the parent page not the child page. I tested it, see the demo.

Comment: Which demo are you referring to? If you call from the page that contains the element (iframe) just do document.getElementsByTagName(). See example in the W3School page.

Comment: On a chrome browser the above code is working fine, how ever with my mobile app it doesn't. why ?

Comment: You have to check element by element the javascript code to see what is not working for the mobile browser. This is somehow a totally new question.

Answer (score -1):

why dont you use jQuery?
- include jquery scripts and then and this right after

```
<script>
$('iframe').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Can't we achieve this by JS? All the code is written in JS here, that's the reason for JS. If it fails I would try jQuery